# In Calendar weekly view how to see more hours of the day

Tags: macos, big-sur, calendar

I would like to see more hours at a time in Calendar's Week view. I thought making the window taller would do this, but it just makes all the events bigger. Enlarging the window vertically just stretches the hours to be taller too.

Comment: when I pinch to zoom-out at maximum I can see hours from 0:00 to 7:00pm

Comment: @tama I can see 0 to 12 but I would like to see at least 1.5x as much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **macOS Big Sur** in **Calendar**, one can show from 6 hours to 24 hours in **Week** *view*, the default is 12 hours, by changing the **Show: [12] hours at a time** *preference* in: **Calendar** > **Preferences…** > **General**

[image]